# MySQL compatibility on AWS Aurora

Tags: amazon-aurora

I was wondering whether MySQL commands like NOLOCK or creation of indexes is actually supported on Aurora AWS? Also, can I do performance issue investigation or is Aurora AWS a "black-box" to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Aurora it is completely different database than MySQL, but when it comes to the compability with MySQL or PostgreSQL Amazon team did a lot so that there would not be a lot of differences. "The Amazon Aurora MySQL is designed to be wire-compatible with MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 using the InnoDB storage engine. Certain MySQL features like the MyISAM storage engine are not available with Amazon Aurora." Amazon Aurora MySQL 2.01 does not currently also support the following MySQL 5.7 features:

- Global transaction identifiers (GTIDs)
- Group replication plugin
- Increased page size
- InnoDB buffer pool loading at startup
- InnoDB full-text parser plugin
- Multisource replication
- Online buffer pool resizing
- Password validation plugin
- Query rewrite plugins
- Replication filtering
- The CREATE TABLESPACE SQL statement
- X Protocol

(source:https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Updates.2022.html)

But it changes from release to release.

Answering to you question about a performance monitoring. You can monitor Aurora database from AWS Console or by using queries directly on Aurora database, the same as in case of MySQL. Staring from version 2.03 there is also available the performance schema.

UNLOCK command - I am not sure whether it also exists in native MySQL, but there is possiblity to set transaction isolation level.

Indexes - yes, you can also create indexes on Aurora.

I hope the information will be useful for you.